# sql condition to not include 4712 date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I always have an issue with date transformation. Can someone guide and help me understanding the date transformation.

I am using the below code in Oracle Fusion HCM Extract tool  and I am getting the correct output

```
APPROVAL_STATUS_CD='APPROVED'
AND ABSENCE_STATUS_CD in ('SUBMITTED','ORA_WITHDRAWN')
and typetl.name != 'Banked Time - Disbursement'
and  (TO_DATE(trunc(start_date) ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
>=  TO_DATE((select trunc((sysdate),'month') as FirstDay from dual),'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

but it is giving me data that has start_date as '4712-12-31' as well. I do not want this in my output. as soon as i add the below condition -

```
and (TO_DATE(trunc(start_date) ,'YYYY') != TO_DATE('YYYY','4712'))
```

I am not getting any output. How do I restrict the 4712 date in the start_Date column i.e. whichever data has 31-12-4712 in start_date should not come in output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there will be no higher values then you want:

```sql
AND start_date < DATE '4712-12-31'
```

*Note: **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` data type.*

Which would make your query:

```sql
WHERE  APPROVAL_STATUS_CD='APPROVED'
AND    ABSENCE_STATUS_CD in ('SUBMITTED','ORA_WITHDRAWN')
AND    typetl.name != 'Banked Time - Disbursement'
AND    start_date >=  TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')
AND    start_date <  DATE '4712-12-31'
```

Comment: START_DATE has timestamp 2019-04-04T08:30:00.000+00:00 . The above code is not giving any output

Comment: @SSA_Tech124 `2019-04-04` is not `>= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')` (which would be `2022-04-01 00:00:00`) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b882ba66e1bb1482d3bf9b498ad0eb45)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't supply all the date elements then Oracle defaults to the first day of the current month; so `TO_DATE('YYYY','4712')` evaluates to 4712-04-01, not 4712-12-31 or 4712-01-01.

If you want a fixed date then it's easier to use a literal: `DATE '4712-12-31'`, or possibly - given the range of valid dates Oracle allows - you really want `DATE '-4712-01-01'` (or `DATE '-4712-12-31'`). I'd check the full actual value you have in your data with `TO_CHAR(start_date, 'SYYYY-MM-DD')`. That will show you if it's BC/BCE (with a negative value) or AD/CE (with a positive value).

---

Also, do not use `TO_DATE()` for a value that is already a date; it might work, or it might do odd things. You don't need to do that. When you do `TO_DATE(trunc(start_date) ,'YYYY-MM-DD')` you're implicitly doing `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(trunc(start_date), <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>) ,'YYYY-MM-DD')` - which relies on the current session's NLS settings. Even if it works today, for you, it will break one day someone else.

Just `trunc(start_date)` and `trunc(sysdate, 'month') is enough. Though there's no point truncating the start_date really - if the truncated value is after the start of the month, so is the original non-truncated value.